# Custom CSS properties or HTML attributes?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm experimenting with parallax scrolling, and I want to do something like:

```
$('.page').each(function() {
    $(this).css("background-position", 
        "center " + ((window.pageYOffset - $(this).offset().top) /
                     $(this).css("speed")) + "px");
});
```

Where speed is an attribute assigned to the specific item that controls the movement speed of an item during scrolling. So I would have something like:

```css
#item { speed: 4; }
```

and

```
<div name="item" class="page"></div>
```

I understand this might not be possible with `CSS`. HTML5 supports custom attributes, but I'd rather declare these things somewhere in the head with other information about the element.
Any recommendations on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why Do you not use JavaScript for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this with CSS. But you can use the HTML5 custom attributes, and if you want to declare everything in the header, as you said in your question, you could use jQuery's own method to bind data to elements:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $.data(selector,'speed',5);
    alert($.data(selector,'speed')); //this will alert 5 now
});
```

The docs are here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

And this one should also work: http://api.jquery.com/data/ - code would look a bit different here:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $(selector).data('speed',5);
    alert($(selector).data('speed')); //this will alert 5 now
});
```

Hope thath helps.

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 with custom `data-` attribute:

```
<div name="item" class="page" data-speed="4"></div>
```

Using jQuery’s [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method in your loop:

```
parseInt($(this).data('speed'), 10);
```

Comment: 'I'd rather declare these things somewhere in the head' - That throws HTML5 out of the race. And using parseInt is absolutely unnecessary when using jQuery.

Comment: Just out of interest: why did you use parseInt here?

Comment: Just a good habit. You expect the `data-speed` attribute to be an integer, but you don't have to assume it is.